# Creating array of 2d arrays

Tags: c

I have a number of arrays

```
double foo[][2] = { {1.0,3.0}, {2.6,10.0}, {0.0,0.0} };
double bar[][2] = { {1.4,3.2}, {2.1,9.9}, {2.1,9.9}, {2.1,9.9}, {0.0,0.0} };
```

So these are both of type:

```
double (*)[2]
```

I want to make an array of these so I need to declare an array of type pointer to array[2]

```
double ((*array)[2])[] = {foo, bar};
```

This syntax doesn't work - is it possible to do this in C.

I also tried to create a type but this didn't work either:

```
typedef double *mytype[2] ;
mytype array[] = {foo, bar};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax to do it without the typedef is:

```
double (*array[])[2] = {foo, bar};
```

Answer (score 3):

The two arrays are not of type `double(*)[2]`. `foo` is of type `double [3][2]` and bar is of type `double [5][2]`. The outer array size is implied, not absent.

To create an array of these, use them as pointers, thus:

```
typedef double (*mytype)[2];
mytype array[] = { foo, bar };
```

Comment: The outer array size can be implied. This isn't the issue I see it is creating an array with the 1st element foo and the 2nd bar.

Comment: The two types are different, so you can't have an array that holds both. So the fact that the implied sizes are different is quite significant. Anyway, the code I presented compiles and runs.

Comment: It does work. It is not purely pointer arithmetic that is being used to find the value of array[0][2][0]. array[0] decays into foo : so foo[2][0].

Answer (score 0):

```
double ((*array)[2])[] = {foo, bar};
```

This don't work, because the memory location of `bar` is not relative to the memory location of `foo`, and the type of `foo` and `bar` isn't equal with the type of elements of `double (*)[2]` which have to be `double` type.

Comment: foo and bar decay into pointers - the issue is how to create an array of pointers to arrays.